# How to test SQL queries by checking the syntax of the command (with the arg values) that gets generated by the library (myBatis)?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis

I have a Spring boot application that uses myBatis to perform CRUD operations. Now in order to test these DB calls, I can write unit test cases using h2 in memory database. Problem is even if h2 database with dialect is set to Oracle SQL, you still have to make changes to the query statement to make it work, this is not preferred (have to additionally work on translating and maintaining). So now instead of using h2, can I directly test the SQL generated by myBatis during runtime? This way I'm testing the DB call on a command level rather than an execution level. SQL queries that I'm using are SELECT, UPDATE

If this is a bad idea, please enlighten me. For now checking the query syntax seems to the most efficient way of testing this. If there is a way to test full extent of Oracle SQL dialect, do let me know.

The queries which I'm using

```
SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_1=VALUE1 AND COLUMN2 BETWEEN TIMESTAMP1 AND TIMESTAMP2 DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Issue at 'DESC FIRST FIRST 1 ROW ONLY'

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2) VALUES(123, SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

SYSTIMESTAMP has different syntax in H2

Usual queries would work fine with H2 in mem, but using some of these commands have led to errors in h2 like ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception etc.

Comment: Comparing generated SQL really is not a good testing strategy, IMHO. Oracle provides an official [docker image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images). For unit testing, [Testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/modules/oracle-xe/) (which internally uses the docker image) seems to be quite popular.

Comment: Can't use Docker. Has to be in the code itself of in mem only. Thank you for your response. I have looked at Testcontainers and it seems like a very good idea for integrating test envs. Unfortunately, docker integration is not possible. Do let me know if there are any approaches to this. Is testing the SQL even possible in this situation?

Comment: Not really. You can get a SQL string with placeholders i.e. `?`, but asserting that string is not particularly valuable as a test. Are you using the latest version of H2? There seems to be some ['fix'](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/3396) regarding `SYSTIMESTAMP` recently. If there is an issue with the compat-mode, you should file a report on their [tracker](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues).  My recommendation, baed on my experience, still is to use an actual Oracle DB (on Docker or otherwise).